# Add timestamp to current time

Tags: anchor, solana-program, rust, anchor-lang, cargo

I need to implement a time-bound function to get the `current_time` and set an `end_time`  The function should add `add_time` to the `current_time` let's say 2 years, 3 months and 4 days if `add_time` in UTC is not provided.

Code Snippet:

```
use anchor_lang::prelude::Clock;

pub fn set_time(
        ctx: Context<ModifyLedger>,
        timestamp_in_utc : String, 
    ) -> Result<()> {

        let clock = Clock::get()?;
        let current_timestamp = clock.unix_timestamp;
        
        if timestap_in_utc {
          add_time = timestap_in_utc;     
        }
        
        else
          add_time = "some hard coded time" 
        
       //now add add_time to current_time to get new time. 
       end_time = ? 

        Ok();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Timestamps on the Solana clock are just `i64` values that represent the number of seconds that have passed, similar to Javascript's `Date.now()`.

If you want to add a specific time period to a clock timestamp, just calculate what that time length is in seconds and do the arithmetic on the `i64` value.

Comment: Thanks buddy I figured that part out as well, now the only issue remains is the conversion of UTC/GMT  time to unix time in anchor.